# Where is the mercurial.hg source repository

Tags: mercurial

I looked at the mercurial website, and I couldn't find a single link to the location of the mercurial source repository itself.
Do you know where it might me?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The official repository seems to sit at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/ or https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg-stable with different branches. More information is available at the [Developer Repositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/DeveloperRepos) wiki page.

Both links are browsable online and can be cloned from:

```
hg clone https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/
hg clone https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg-stable
```

Comment: They make it super hard to find... They really don't want people putting fingers into it... You are supposed to do all your work in super-slow python, which Mercurial is already slow compared to Git.

Comment: @Matej'Yin'Gagyi Mercurial is gradually porting to Rust https://wiki.mercurial-scm.org/OxidationPlan

Answer (score 1):

The source release is available from the [downloads](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads) page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the Source:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/?M=D